# Creating a subset in R using date

Tags: r, dataset

I'm new in R and I need some help getting some things done.
First of all I have to analyse a huge dataset 766K rows with 2 columns in the form below:

```
G40 2003-04-09
Z11 1997-08-15
K60 2006-03-16
I10 2000-11-30
```

The name of the dataset is `Rdiagnoses`and there is no header so by default `Col1 is V1` and `Col2 is V2`. The first column is the diagnoses and the second the date which it was diagnosed.
First I was thinking on creating a subset for each year separably. The way I'm try to do it is this way however it gives me an error.

```
diagnoses2009 <- as.Date( as.character(Rdiagnoses$V2), "%d-%m-%y")

Rdiagnoses_2009 <- subset(Rdiagnoses, V2 >= as.Date("2009-01-01") & V2 <= as.Date("2009-12-31") )

 Warning messages:

1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.Date") for ">="

2: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.Date") for "<="
```

Any suggestions of correcting that of a better way of choosing each year is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If I had to guess, `V2` is a factor, not a date column.

Comment: I don't think you're coercing your date column correctly. Try `x <- c("2003-04-09", "09-04-2003");as.Date(x, format = "%d-%m-%Y")` (notice capital Y and order of days, months and years).

Comment: Are you planning to do some operations on each of the subsetted pieces of data? If yes, there may be an easier way than to create a separate data.frame per year. If you describe more detailed what you want to do, I'm sure someone will suggest something

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple of things going on here.

First, you (try to) set `diagnoses2009` to a set of dates, but your subset expression does not use that variable at all.

Second, as @joran points out you are using the wrong format string: your dates are formatted as `%Y-%m-%d`. When you run `as.Date(...)` with an incorrect format string, you get `NA` for all the dates. So `diagnoses2009` is a vector of `NA`.

Third, there are much better ways to split a dataframe. You could do this for example:

```
library(lubridate)
df.subsets <- split(df,year(as.Date(df$V2, "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

This creates a list of data frames, one for each year.

Finally, as @beginnerR points out, you didn't tell us anything about what you are planning to do with the split datasets. There might be a *much* better way to deal with your overall problem.